# Swift - How to detect an action button in UItableViewCell is pressed from ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an action button in UITableViewCell and I would like to detect when the button is pressed and the pressed cell's number from ViewController to make an audio play list in ViewController.swift.

I have been stuck in this problem for a while and I would really appriciate your advice. Here are the codes.

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "Cell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! Cell
        return cell

    }


}
```

Cell.swift

```
import UIKit

class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        ***[Code to send the pressed cell's number to ViewController]***

    }

}
```

Comment: Look for delegate.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could go for a good old fashioned delegate pattern. This has the advantage of not coupling your view controller from your cell. Don't forget to make your delegate `weak` to avoid retain cycles.

The you can find the cell index path from the table view. (I'm assuming by cell number you mean index path)

```
protocol CellDelegate: class {
    func didTap(_ cell: Cell)
}

class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var delegate: CellDelegate?
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.didTap(self)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, CellDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = ...
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func didTap(_ cell: Cell) {
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
        // do something with the index path
    }
}
```

Comment: Your implementation of `didTap` is strange. Just do: `let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell)`. No need to scan the visible cells.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this Inside your ViewConroller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! Cell

        //add tag to cell button to that of cell index
        cell.button.tag = indexPath.row

         //Observer for button click event inside cell
         cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell

    }

//Mark: Button Action

@objc func pressButton(_ button: UIButton) {
    print("Button with tag: \(button.tag) clicked in cell!")
}
```